# Getting totals from two javascript functions to add together

Tags: javascript

I have 3 functions, two of which produce a total depending on selections in a form, the other formats the output. They currently display independently as separate running totals, but i need to add them together as one total. I guess that i need to return them as variables and then create a new function to add them together, is that right?

```
function addem(oSelect)
{
    var total = 0, oForm = oSelect.form;
    var i = 0, sel, sels = oForm.getElementsByTagName('select');
    while (sel = sels[i++])
        if (sel.className == 'items')
            total += parseFloat(prices[sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value] || 0, 10);
    document.getElementById('output').value = format(total);
}

function format(sAmount)
{
    sAmount = Math.round(sAmount * 100) / 100;
    return  '£' + ((sAmount != parseInt(sAmount)) ? sAmount : sAmount + '.00');
}

function checkTotal() {
    document.quote.total2.value = '';
    var sum = 0;
    for (i=0;i<document.quote.SMM.length;i++) {
      if (document.quote.SMM[i].checked) {
        sum = sum + parseInt(document.quote.SMM[i].value);
      }
    }
    document.quote.total2.value = format(sum);
}
```

Comment: Correct, that's what I would do. Have all the methods return their own total and then have a method that does the sum of all three.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of them inside the other so the main one will show the final result, exactly like using format inside checkTotal.

Comment: Would that be adding an 'else' to the 'addem' function using the code from checkTotal as it need to update the total dynamically.